# Error while setup Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2.4.2, xampp, windows10

I am trying to install Magento 2.4.2 , and I am getting this error

```
PHP Warning:  require(C:\xampp-clean\htdocs\magento242\vendor\composer/../phpsta
n/phpstan/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:
\xampp-clean\htdocs\magento242\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 73
```

The command that I am used that is causing this error is :

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://ahmed.magento/" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento242" --db-user="root" --db-password="" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="contact@code.tn" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="azerty123" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin" --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host="localhost" --elasticsearch-port=9200
```

I am using as system :
Windows 10

with xampp software ,
Elasticsearch is running and working.
Do anyone has any idea about this problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have used this and it works for me

- Delete Composer Folder (vendor/composer)
- Delete Autoload.php (vendor/autoload.php) Then, write on the console:

  composer install

  composer update